# R shiny - SelectizeInput with either/or options

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `selectizeInput` with 6 options in it: A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2.

Right now I have the following code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple", multiple = T, 
                 choices = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"))
```

And it produces this:

[image: select]

If you want a minimal reproduceable example, then here's a shiny app with it.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple", multiple = T, 
                 choices = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"))
)

server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want however, is for **only one of each type of letter to be selectable**.

A1, B1, C2, is fine, but A1, A2 is not. In other words, A1 and A2 are in a group, B1 and B2 are in a group etc. and only one from each group can be selected.

There are two ways to have this feature.

1. Once A1 is selected, then A2 disappears from the remaining choices. The user would have to remove A1 to get A2 (and A1) back in the remaining choices
2. Once A1 is selected, A2 is still in the remaining choices, but then if A2 is selected, A1 is unselected and falls back into the remaining choices

Is there any way to do this with, say, `updateSelectizeInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exclusion part could be done fancier by some experts here =) Concerning the shiny part it should meet your requirements.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  global <- reactiveValues(choices = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"))
  output$select <-  renderUI({
    selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple", multiple = T, choices = global$choices)
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$select)){
      # exclude by comparing first Letters
      firstLetterSelected <- as.character(sapply(input$select, substr, 1, 1))
      firstLetterAllChoices <- as.character(sapply(global$choices, substr, 1, 1))
      subset <- sort(c(input$select, global$choices[which(!(firstLetterAllChoices %in% firstLetterSelected))]))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "select", choices = subset, selected = input$select)
    }else{
      # if inputs are erased completely this list is not refreshed without this else statement
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "select", choices = global$choices, selected = input$select)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Accepted. The letter options (A1, A2..) were actually just for demonstration and my real code has different option names... but I've managed to adapt your code to work for other options too. Thanks!